# Need multiple host output in single file

Tags: ansible

I need to generate single output file with proper format for multiple host 
inventory : hosts

i tried using hostvar and i'm getting them on single file but output format is weird to work with. i need output in the format like HOSTNAME and corresponding output.

```
- name: Network_device_discovery
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  connection: network_cli

  tasks:
    - name: gather outputs using command mod
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - sh run | i logging host

      register: print_output

    - debug: var=print_output.stdout_lines

    - name: save output to a file

      copy:
        content: "{% for hosts in groups.all %}{{ hostvars[hosts].print_output }}\n{% endfor %}"
        dest: res.txt
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

output which i'm getting for this code:

```
{'failed': False, u'changed': False, u'stdout_lines': [[u'logging host 10.0.10.10']], u'stdout': [u'logging host 10.0.10.10']}
{'failed': False, u'changed': False, u'stdout_lines': [[u'logging host 10.0.10.10']], u'stdout': [u'logging host 10.0.10.10']}
```

is there any way i get outputs in the form like:

Device1 : `logging host 10.0.10.10`
Device2 : `logging host 10.0.10.10`

i dont want all those extra words in the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `parse_cli` filter to transform the `cli` output into a data structure you can manipulate. On this GitHub repo, you'll find some examples that you can adapt to your problem. Here is an example of how you would use it.

First, the playbook. We want to parse the `show vlan` command output:

```
- hosts: all
  connection: connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  become_method: enable
  become_pass: password
  vars:
    vlan_spec_file: './specs/ios/show_vlan.yml'
  tasks:
    - name: Run `show vlan` command
      ios_command:
        commands: show vlan
      register: output
    - name: Create a list of dictionaries for each vlan
      set_facts:
        vlans: "{{ output.stdout[0] | parse_cli(vlan_spec_file) }}
```

The `parse_cli` filter expects a `spec` file. In it, you provide a regular expression to find the output with named sections. You then use this sections to create the data structure. Here is what the `spec` file inside `./specs/ios/show_vlan.yml` could look like:

```
vars:
  vlan:
    id: "{{ item.id }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    status: "{{ item.status }}"
    ports: "{{ (item.ports|replace('Gi', 'GigabitEthernet') | replace('Po','PortChannel')).split(', ') }}"

keys:
  vlans:
    value: "{{ vlan }}"
    items: "^(?P<id>\\d+)\\s+(?P<name>\\S+)\\s+(?P<status>[a-z]{4,})\\s*(?P<ports>([A-Za-z]+).+)?"
```

Let's break it down. Inside the `vars` key, you create the different representations you want for your data. In our case, we have one: a `vlan`. Then, in the `keys` value, we construct the dictionary output. In our example, we'll have a dictionary with just one key, which we'll be a list of `vlan` dictionaries. How are we going to populate this `vlans` list? By parsing the `cli` output with a regular expression.

Each named section (those represented by `(?P<some_name><reg_exp>)`) will be passed to each of the `representations` we defined earlier inside an `item` dictionary.

So, with our regular expression, we take the `id`, `name`, `status`, and `ports` information from each `vlan` in the `cli` output text. The `parse_cli` filter is smart enough to break the text into chunks where it applies our regular expression. The results are then passed iteratively to our `vars` representations, and the result is composed of what we defined in our `keys`.

The result would look something like this in `JSON`:

```
{
   "ansible_facts":{
      "ios_vlans":{
         "vlans":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"default",
               "ports":[
                  "GigabitEthernet0/1",
                  "GigabitEthernet0/2",
                  "GigabitEthernet0/3",
                  "GigabitEthernet1/0"
               ],
               "status":"active"
            },
            {
               "id":200,
               "name":"vlan200",
               "ports":[
                  ""
               ],
               "status":"active"
            },
            {
               "id":300,
               "name":"vlan300",
               "ports":[
                  ""
               ],
               "status":"active"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I hope it helps